# Android Custom gallery

Tags: android, gallery

I have a image with the size of 1299 * 625. I want to show the image in Gallery view like  first half is one page and second of is another page. Sorry for my Bad English..

Comment: Do you want to scroll to see each halfs?

Comment: Yes Ahamad. You are Correct..

Comment: Thn you wight want your picture to set as background image and then ad a horizontalscrollview on it

Answer (score 0):

Use the [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) and add two ImageViews to it. Split you image in half and assign each half to one ImageView.